# Tangents face the same direction on opposite sides of mesh

Tags: opengl, graphics-programming

I have noticed that the tangent vectors that I am calculating are not always facing the correct direction. The tangents on the left and right of the mesh both face the same direction. Here is a screenshot showing this:

[image: Incorrect tangent calculations]

I've mapped the XYZ value of the tangent vectors to RGB values in the fragment shader. +Z is towards the camera. As you can see, both sides of the teapot have tangents facing towards the camera instead of only the left as I'd excepted.

Also, the UVs for the mesh are correct and increase smoothly across the surface (I used blender's default sphere mapping to generate the UV coordinates):

[image: UV visualisation of X on red channel]
[image: UV visualisation of X on red channel - back]

The tangents are correct even over the seams.

I am using the following piece of code to compute my tangents:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < mesh.face_list.size(); ++i)
{
    const Face& face = mesh.face_list[i];

    const size_t& i1 = face.vertex_indices[0];
    const size_t& i2 = face.vertex_indices[1];
    const size_t& i3 = face.vertex_indices[2];

    const Vec3& p1 = mesh.vertex_list[i1-1];
    const Vec3& p2 = mesh.vertex_list[i2-1];
    const Vec3& p3 = mesh.vertex_list[i3-1];

    // Compute edges.
    Vec3 e1 = p2 - p1;
    Vec3 e2 = p3 - p1;

    const size_t& txi1 = face.texcoord_indices[0];
    const size_t& txi2 = face.texcoord_indices[1];
    const size_t& txi3 = face.texcoord_indices[2];

    Vec2 texcoordDelta1 = mesh.texcoord_list[txi2-1] - mesh.texcoord_list[txi1-1];
    Vec2 texcoordDelta2 = mesh.texcoord_list[txi3-1] - mesh.texcoord_list[txi1-1];

    float coefficient = 1.0f / (texcoordDelta1.x * texcoordDelta2.y - texcoordDelta2.x * texcoordDelta1.y);
    Vec3 faceTangent = coefficient * (texcoordDelta2.y * e1 - texcoordDelta1.y * e2);

    const size_t& ti1 = face.normal_indices[0];
    const size_t& ti2 = face.normal_indices[1];
    const size_t& ti3 = face.normal_indices[2];

    // Add tangent to all vertices making up the face.
    mesh.tangent_list[ti1-1] += faceTangent;
    mesh.tangent_list[ti2-1] += faceTangent;
    mesh.tangent_list[ti3-1] += faceTangent;
}

// Normalise and orthogonalise all tangents.
for (size_t i = 0; i < mesh.tangent_list.size(); ++i)
{
    mesh.tangent_list[i] = normalise(mesh.tangent_list[i] - (mesh.normal_list[i] * dot(mesh.normal_list[i], mesh.tangent_list[i])));
}
```

As far as I can tell, the main part of the calculation seems correct compared to things I've found online:

```
float coefficient = 1.0f / (texcoordDelta1.x * texcoordDelta2.y - texcoordDelta2.x * texcoordDelta1.y);
Vec3 faceTangent = coefficient * (texcoordDelta2.y * e1 - texcoordDelta1.y * e2);
```

Generally, normal mapping works great, but there are subtle lighting errors on parts of the mesh after the incorrect tangent space transformation. Hopefully this is all of the information needed to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: My own implementations of Vec3 and Vec2 seemed to have a bug in their operator overloads. Switching to a library (glm) completely fixed the issue. Although I couldn't work out exactly where the bug was.